# Using synchronizers from concurrent package. FutureTask always returns null

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Can anyone tell why in the following snippet using a `FutureTask` does not work?
My understanding is that we can use `FutureTask`, right?
To give a full description:
I have stumbled across some subtle bug in my code.
Briefly I have created a class that uses a `SingleThreadPoolExecutor` to run `Callable`s passed as parameters.
I use it in order to run background tasks and display a progress dialog in an Eclipse application.
Code is:

```
public class TaskRunner <T>  {  

    final static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  
    private T taskResult;  

    public T runTask(Callable<T> task, Shell currentShell) throws CustomException{          
        if(currentShell == null){  
            currentShell = new Shell();  
        }  
        final Callable<T> taskToRun = task;       

        ProgressMonitorDialog progressDialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(currentShell);  
        try {  
            progressDialog.run(false, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {  

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
                @Override  
                public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {  
                    monitor.beginTask("Saving your data!", 100);  

                    FutureTask<T> task = createTask(taskToRun);  
                    Future<?> result = threadPool.submit(task);  
                    while(!result.isDone()){  
                        monitor.worked(1);  
                    }                     
                    try {  
                        taskResult = (T) result.get();  
                        if(taskResult == null){  
                            System.out.println("Result here in return is NULL!");  
                        }  

                    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {  
                        logger.error(e1);  
                    }   
                    catch(Exception e){  
                        logger.error(e);  
                    }               
                }  
            });  
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {  
            logger.error(e);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            logger.error(e);  
        }       
        return taskResult;  
    }  

    private static <T> FutureTask<T> createTask(Callable<T> theTask){  
        return new FutureTask<T>(theTask);   
    }  
}
```

And the code task:

```
public class MyTask implements Callable<ComplexObject> {    

    private Util helper;  
    private String filePath;  

    public LoadKeystoreTask(Util helper, String filePath) {  
        this.helper = helper;     
        this.filePath = filePath;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Container call() throws Exception {        
        ComplexObject result = helper.loadData(filePath);  
        if(result == null){  
            System.out.println("ComplexObject IS NULL!");  
        }  
        else{  
            System.out.println("ComplexObject IS NOT NULL!");  
        }   
        return result;  
    }  
}
```

**Problem:**
While the `helper.loadData` correctly returns the result (verified via debugging and print statements) this line:

```
taskResult = (T) result.get();
```

**always** is `null`.
I.e to simplify it is printed:

> ComplexObject IS NOT NULL!
>   Result here in return is NULL!

This is verified to be caused by submitting a `FutureTask`.
If I submit a `Callable` instead:

I.e. just chang to:

```
Future<?> result = threadPool.submit(taskToRun);
```

it works! Why does wrapping with `FutureTask` causes this problem?

Comment: Why are you wrapping tasks in `FutureTask`? You are free to `submit()` `Callable` directly.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:Hm,yes it was by accident.I meant to call `isDone` and originally I thought it was part of `FutureTask` api.

Answer (score 2):

`FutureTask` is unnecessary here:

```
private static <T> FutureTask<T> createTask(Callable<T> theTask){  
    return new FutureTask<T>(theTask);   
}

FutureTask<T> task = createTask(taskToRun);  
Future<?> result = threadPool.submit(task);
```

just `submit()` `Calleble<T>` directly:

```
Future<?> result = threadPool.submit(taskToRun);
```

I don't think [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) is meant to be used in user code:

> This class provides a base implementation of `Future`

Leave implementing `Future` to libraries.

Comment: Ok, but why does wrapping with `FutureTask` makes `Future#get()` to always return `null`?

Comment: @Cratylus: no idea, but I've never seen using this class in such a scenario, I guess it's just wrong API usage.

Comment: :But in `Java Concurrency in Practice` it does not mention that `FutureTask` is not to be used.It also has example using it in page 95 if you have it handy

Comment: @Cratylus: interesting, +1. I'll wait then, maybe someone more experienced knows the reason to use that class.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple. `FutureTask` is `Runnable` so the exact method of `ExecutorService` you call would be `Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`. Now let's have a look at the javadoc:

> Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future
>   representing that task. The Future's get method will
>   return **null** upon successful completion...

That's very understandable. `Runnable` contains only `void run()` method. What result do you want it to return?

If you submit `FutureTask` to `Executor` just use it to obtain the result:

```
FutureTask<Integer> task = ...
threadPool.submit(task);
result = task.get();
```

Comment: But how do you know that the `task` you passed in the `threadPool` will have the result?

Comment: @Cratylus from the javadoc to `FutureTask`: "...A `FutureTask` can be used to wrap a `Callable` or `Runnable` object. Because `FutureTask` implements `Runnable`, a `FutureTask` can be submitted to an `Executor` for execution..."

Comment: I am not sure why this is so obvious to you.For example why doesn't it return the passed-in `FutureTask` instead to get the result?It  `FutureTask`

Comment: @Cratylus you call `submit(Runnable task)` on executor. So your `FutureTask` is treated like one. What do you think the executor is supposed to do? Do you want it to check if the argument `instanceof FutureTask` and if so then return it back to the caller?

Comment: Hm.No, it is just that for some reason it is not apparent to me as it is to you from the javadoc.I will accept this answer as soon as I verify this